# Automatic language specific code formatting

Tags: feature-request

I ran across this meta topic today, [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), which says the tags associated with a question set the default [code prettifying](https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for that topic. A great idea! However it's not clear where those associations are set. Is this a moderator only option? or tag-wiki or...?

In particular these tags should be language python:
[python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python),[arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy),[python26](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python26),[mod-python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-python),[numpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numpy)

Answer (score 2):

This is a test of things here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting
This is marked with  language: c# ...

```
public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
```

... doesn't generate any colors - maybe it is a bug?

Or maybe it isn't used for meta.gis.se ?

Comment: hey Kirk, nice rep number, 8888, as of this moment. (no I have no idea why an arbitrary sequence like that is any more or less pleasing to me than another like, say, 4093. Nonetheless it is :)

Answer (score 1):

It's set on the tag info page, as in this one for [C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/info).

I suspect it requires 5K+ (possibly more) or mod privileges to change.

I have recently been checking this setting when I review tag wiki edits.  In many cases it hasn't been set yet, but it works (apparently correctly) for some of the commonest language-related tags including [python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and [c#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

I don't know whether this mechanism would work on a meta page.

Comment: well I can edit the c# tag, but the edits are under probation until okayed by a moderator. I don't however see anyplace or text for setting the language type. It looks like I might break 5k in a little while so I can report then if there is anything new. It would be nice if non-mod/super-users could at least see the definitions if not change them.

Comment: @matt you're right: the language setting option I see on sites I moderate does not appear on sites where I have 3K - 5K rep.  As a work around for the present, consider flagging a tag by making an inconsequential edit and putting your request in the "Edit Summary" textbox.