# Syntax highlighting for openlayers-3 tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I've just spend a bit of time tagging openlayers-3 Q's as 'javascript' in order to enable syntax highlighting.  But, I've just realized that you can create language specification for tags: [Automatic language specific code formatting](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/573/automatic-language-specific-code-formatting/574#574)

Would someone with enough power be able to link the openlayers-3 tag to 'lang-js'?  It would make troubleshooting the issues a lot easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just visited https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/openlayers-3/info and set its Code Language to `lang-js` (as below).

It does not seem to allow setting of more than one language and in any event you have since commented:

> It appears that lang-js implies HTML and CSS. No need for the
>   additional HTML tag as requested.

I have also updated https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/openlayers-2/info to have the same setting.

I thought about updating https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/openlayers/info too, but since [openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers) is now a synonym of [openlayers-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-2) there seems no point to us doing that.

[image]